How to resolve absolute path using snack expo dev?
I know how to resolve absolute path using React Native locally, my problem is using snack.
I'm using snack expo dev: https://snack.expo.dev/@danilobatistaqueiroz/water-tracker
If I try to import a module using absolute path, I get an error because the path has duplicated src folder: Unable to resolve module://src/src/libraries/storage.js
//src/components/insights/insights.js
import {saveData, getData} from '/src/libraries/storage';

How to resolve the absolute path correctly?
It seems my babel config isn't working:
//babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        "babel-plugin-root-import",
        {
          "rootPathPrefix": "@",
          "rootPathSuffix": "src",
        }
      ],
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ["./"],
          alias: {
            assets: './assets',
            components: './src/components',
            libraries: './src/libraries'
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};

I tried using babel.config.json
I tried using the imports below and it didn't work:
import {saveData, getData} from '@/libraries/storage';
import {saveData, getData} from 'libraries/storage';
import {saveData, getData} from 'src/libraries/storage';




Maybe try:
import {saveData, getData} from 'src/libraries/storage';

I removed the / at the start of the import path.

I tried that path, it didn't work for me.

Thank you for logging this issue: https://github.com/expo/snack/issues/599

It seems that snacks can't interpret the babel config files.

Seems that way.  I see mention of "snackager" in some issues that seem related to yours, but I've no experience with it.
